# Adobe air 21 cannot connect to WSDl service

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, air

iam using adobe flex to developer an app on ios  and android
until air 19 i used to connect to asp.net xml webservice using wsdl and it works great
when adobe released air 20 and 21 this is no longer working the code is not working and not accessing  my server
does anyone know what i should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of Apple's new limitation on network connections. 
you have to add below manifest to your app.xml file to prevent this problem any more:

```
<iPhone>

    <InfoAdditions>

    <![CDATA[

        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>

        <dict>

        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>

        </dict>

    ]]>

    </InfoAdditions>

</iPhone>
```

Answer (score -1):

This problems occurs in iOS and Android?

Comment: This is a question not an answer. Better to make it a comment on the question instead.

Comment: yes on both on air 19 its perfect above no connection